# mongodb one to many relationship nested array lookup?

Tags: mongodb

Sub category name not render properly.

Table 1 : advertisements

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("650c053c0d606e3db1e882e1"),

    "name" : "mtesting",
    "short_desc" : "sfdhgsfghdf",
    "description" : "xcvsdfgsdfg",
    "status" : 1,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2023-09-21T14:26:28.397+05:30"),
    "__v" : 0,
    "amount" : NumberDecimal("100"),
    "categoryID" : ObjectId("6500738369cb6aaf6b26eea8"),
    "createdBy" : ObjectId("64fad2dab11e29c07682bb2e"),
        "slug":"mtesting"
    "subCategoryId" : ObjectId("6500738369cb6aaf6b26eeab")
}
```

Table 2 : categories

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6500738369cb6aaf6b26eea8"),

    "categoryName" : "Real Estate",
    "categoryBgImage" : "static/bgimage/dbrr3om91aw000000000",
    "status" : "Active",
    "subCategory" : [
        {
            "subCategoryName" : "Apartments",
            "status" : "Active",
            "_id" : ObjectId("6500738369cb6aaf6b26eeaa"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2023-09-12T19:49:47.365+05:30")
        },
        {
            "subCategoryName" : "Townhouses",
            "status" : "Active",
            "_id" : ObjectId("6500738369cb6aaf6b26eeab"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2023-09-12T19:49:47.365+05:30")
        },
        
    ],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2023-09-12T19:49:47.366+05:30"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I tried query as

```
db.advertisements.aggregate([

    {
        $match: {
               "slug" : "testing"
        },
    },
    {
        $limit: 1,
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "categories",
            "localField": "categoryID",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "categoriesData"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$categoriesData",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "categories",
            "localField": "subCategoryId",
            "foreignField": "subCategory._id",
            "as": "subCategoryData"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 1,
            slug: 1,
            amount: { $concat: [{ $toString: "$amount" }] },
            createdAt: {
                $dateToString: {
                    format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%m",
                    date: "$createdAt",
                },
            },
            status: 1,
            short_desc: 1,
            description: 1,
            categoryName: "$categoriesData.categoryName",
            subCategoryData: 1,
        },
    },
]);
```

Sub category name not rendered properly, am expecting result as

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("650c053c0d606e3db1e882e1"),

    "name" : "murali kanna testing",
    "short_desc" : "sfdhgsfghdf",
    "description" : "xcvsdfgsdfg",
    "status" : 1,
    "slug" : "testing",
    "amount" : "100",
    "createdAt" : "2023-09-21 08:09",
    "categoryName" : "Real Estate",
    "subcategoryName" : "Townhouses"
}
```

Comment: In your category, there are subcategories like "Apartments", "Townhouses", is there any condition that should show which subcategoryName?

Comment: I need lookup using _id (object id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost to the answer. Since the `subCategory` is associated in the `category` document, you don't need the second `$lookup` stage to join with `category` collection for the `subCategory`.

To get the `subCategoryName`:

1. `$filter` - Filter the element in `categoriesData.subCategory` array to find the matching `_id`.
2. `$first` - Get the first matching element from the result (1).
3. `$getField` - Get the `subCategoryName` value from the result (2).

```
db.advertisements.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "slug": "testing"
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "categories",
      "localField": "categoryID",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "categoriesData"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$categoriesData",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      name: 1,
      slug: 1,
      amount: {
        $concat: [
          {
            $toString: "$amount"
          }
        ]
      },
      createdAt: {
        $dateToString: {
          format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%m",
          date: "$createdAt"
        }
      },
      status: 1,
      short_desc: 1,
      description: 1,
      categoryName: "$categoriesData.categoryName",
      subCategoryName: {
        $getField: {
          input: {
            $first: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$categoriesData.subCategory",
                cond: {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$this._id",
                    "$subCategoryId"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          field: "subCategoryName"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YgIcluS5UjP)